# How to determine why MariaDB is removing all rows once they've been added

Tags: sql, mariadb, innodb

I'm copying rows from one table's database to an identical table in another database using this query:

```
INSERT INTO db122.link_table
SELECT * FROM db119.link_table
```

There are 25 million rows, and they get inserted correctly. Once the rows are all inserted (takes like 8 hours) they begin to slowly, automatically be removed over the course of 2-3 days until the db119.link_table is empty again.

I'm just running the query in the phpmyadmin console. It's MariaDB 10 and the engine is InnoDB. Auto commit is on and there are no triggers on the destination DB/table.

I would expect there to be somewhere I can view what error is occurring to cause the removal. The initial query is shown in the general log, but no errors or remove queries are shown in that log or the error log. I'm not sure where to go from here tracking this down.

Comment: the insert succeeds and you see all the rows there in a new transaction?

Comment: MySQL will **NEVER** just do this. If you can see the data in queries from subsequent transactions, they are there in the database until someone deletes them. This means you have _something_ out there deleting these rows.

Comment: I suspect you've exceeded the logging high water mark, but you have read uncommitted on, so you see the rows, but they are slowly rolled back. Do the insertion in chunks of say 100K rows.

Comment: Check for errors after the INSERT..SELECT;

Comment: Did you commit the transaction?